# JSONModel: Filling an NSArray of generic type

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsonmodel, objc-protocol

I'm using JSONModel in my iOS app and i'm facing some warnings, let me explain myself a bit.

Let's say i have this JSONModel

**CTVContact.h**

```
@interface CTVContact : JSONModel
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<Optional, CTVPhone> *phone;
@end
```

**CTVContact.m**

```
NSMutableArray *phones = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSString *p in personPhones) {
    CTVPhone *phn = [[CTVPhone alloc] init];
    phn.original = p;
    [phones addObject:phn];
}    
phone = [NSArray arrayWithArray:phones];
```

Basically it all works like a charm but i get a warning stating the following:

```
Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSArray<Optional,CTVEventParticipant> *' from 'NSArray *'
```

How can i go around that warning? I can't find the right way to assign all the array values to the phone Array without that warning.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NSArray<Optional, CTVPhone> *phone;` defines a variable that takes an array which conforms to 2 protocols. If you try and set that a variable (`phone`) to an array that doesn't state that it conforms to those protocols then you will get a compile warning.

`phone = [NSArray arrayWithArray:phones];` just creates a 'plain' array, with no special protocols implemented. So you get a warning.

Probably the correct thing to do is to remove the protocols from the @property definition. Unless you have an `NSArray` subclass which conforms to those protocols that you should actually be using...

Alternatively, and assuming that you don't try to call any methods that might be defined in those protocols:

```
phone = (NSArray <Optional, CTVPhone> *)[NSArray arrayWithArray:phones];
```

which adds a cast that basically means to the compiler: 'trust me, it's fine'...

Comment: If i remove the protocols, JSONModel stops working and it doesn't model the JSON correctly, look at the Model Collections section here: https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/blob/master/README.md#magical-data-modelling-framework-for-json

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may be complaining on your last line, since you're passing in an `NSMutableArray` when `NSArray`'s [`arrayWithArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithArray%3a) method calls for an `NSArray`. You can get away with this by calling `copy` on the `phones` array, as such:

```
phone = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[phones copy]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no, that did not fix it, the main issue is that in the interface i say the array is an NSArray<Something> and i try to copy an NSarray to it, so it says NSArray<Something> != NSArray

Comment: @asheinfeld, why are you adding the `<Something>` then?

Comment: So that JSONModel works :). That is the way they ask you to do it.